# Error when trying to send UDP over network

Tags: python, udp

I am attempting to communicate with an ETC EOS lighting console with a raspberry pi over a local network.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.1.10.149"
UDP_PORT = "0"
MESSAGE = "$ Channel 1 @ FULL #"

print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

The error I am receiving is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/eoscontrol.py", line 13, in <module>
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I change my string to bytes to resolve this error?

I am very new to python, I'd bet this is something pretty simple, I just don't know it well yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to the send data in byte format by encoding it first. The below should work for you

```
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, 'utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this and got the following error: 
```sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, 'utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument```

Comment: try using ```UDP_PORT = 0``` without the ""

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the same error. I think I'm probably not using the right method for what I'm trying to accomplish. The documentation on the ETC console itself does not delve into anything regarding coding, so there is not much help there. I found something that says the Serial Group ID from the device wanting to communicate must match the Rx ID in the console settings. Do you know if that is something that could be set within the python code?

Comment: Without seeing the documentation it's difficult to know, but I wouldn't of thought it would be a python issue